# eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I diagonalized an arbitrary 3x3 symmetric matrix using two SO matrices at respective angles and the diagonal elements are nothing but eigenvalues. I separately found eigenvalues with the help of characteristic equation. My question is, how to compare the two sets of eigenvalues for the initial ones are in angles and matrix elements and the later in purely matrix elements. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: look at the eigenvectors.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?